# How do I created a nested database in Firebase through a React action creator?

Tags: javascript, reactjs, firebase, redux, google-cloud-firestore

I want to add an object, instead of a single field, to my Firebase data through an action creator.   The database will have a nested structure like the following:

- Item:

  - Name
  - Description
  - Booking info

    - Booking date
    - Renter name

Following is my action creator:

```
export const book = bookingDate => {
    return (dispatch, getState, {getFirebase, getFirestore}) => {
        const firebase = getFirebase();
        const firestore = getFirestore();
        const profile = getState().firebase.profile;
        const userId = getState().firebase.auth.uid;    
        firestore.collection('items').doc(bookingDate.itemId).set({
            booking: {...bookingDate,
            renterFirstname: profile.firstName,
            renterLastname: profile.lastName,
            renterId: userId,
            createdAt: new Date()
            }
        }).then(() => {
            dispatch({ type: BOOKING_SUCCESS });
        }).catch( err => {
            dispatch({ type: BOOKING_ERROR }, err);
        });
    }
}
```

The set() method replaces the existing information with the new data, which isn't what I want.  I tried the add() method, but I'm not sure how to retrieve the existing data at the same time so that I can use the spread operator.

Comment: I believe there is an update method.. yes there is: https://firebase.google.com/docs/firestore/manage-data/add-data#update_fields_in_nested_objects

Comment: update() also replaces all the values within "book" value.  How do I set up so that they are given a new key each time I add a new entry?